# Plugin to allow remote reboot of slave?

Tags: jenkins

We have a a build farm, that ideally should have as part of it's configuration a nightly cronjob to reboot nodes (spread the reboots over the week).

In the interim though, because I don't want to have to go and completely recreate every build farm node again (I mean I *could*... and eventually I will because of other needs) I was wondering if there's a Jenkins plugin somewhere that allows remote rebooting of a slave node from the UI.

I know that reboot requires sudo rights, just wondering if there was a nice remote "Nuke the slave from orbit" option anywhere.. ?

And yes, you can just tell me to stop being lazy and go redo the images..

Comment: Do you need to reboot the entire slave server, or just restart the slave process ?  Maybe you could provide some background on why you need to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a job which creates a crontab which triggers a reboot. Have one for each node. Have the job ensure that crontab | grep -c reboot has $! of 0 .... (indicating a reboot has been scheduled as part of system crontab) or create the crontab to do this reboot.

If you want to get really fancy, you'd have a script which automatically marks the slave as offline and then touches a reboot-ready file, where the @weekly reboot-script checks the existence of said file (and removes it) and then does the reboot.

Comment: Two issues to worry about here:  1. crontab is asychronous relative to any job that may run on the slave so you could end up rebooting a slave in the middle of an important job (like halfway through deploying critical infrastructure) so the "mark offline" step going first is important. 2. The "mark offline" also needs to be aware if a job is currently running.  Both of those problems can be solved if you: A. Limit the slave to one executor, and B: write a time based Jenkins job to do the actual reboot. Not ideal, however.